# RecyclerView set items all at once when is inside scrollView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

When you create dynamic list using `RecyclerView` your aim is to display needed item to user not all at once that causes to wait user to see the list. But i recently noticed that when you put `RecyvlerView` inside `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` deveice waits for recyclerview to insert all items and then display recyclerview to user, i suspect that recyclerView doesn't recycle items which makes user wait for almost 1.5 second.

**Question:**
How can i put `Recyclerview` inside `NestedScrollView` and have recyclerview normal behaviour which is recycling items not showing them all at once.

RecyclerView implementation codes:

fragment_translate_from.xml Codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
</data>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_translate_from"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".features.translate_from_from.ui.translate_fromFromFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/translate_from_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/translate_from_tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_minus7sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_translate_from_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/per_vazir_regular_font"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/translate_From_title"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_translate_from_search"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_translate_from_back_arrow"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_translate_from_back_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_arrow_ripple_effect"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_search"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_close_24"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:hintEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_translate_from_back_arrow"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_search_24">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_search_input"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
                        android:hint="@string/languages_search_str"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/enter_text_color"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/enter_text_color"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor_drawable"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_translate_from_search"
                    android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_arrow_ripple_effect"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/views_layout_translate_from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/views_scroll_views"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/inner_views_layout_translate_from"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_all_languages"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="@string/all_languages_str"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/all_langs_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_all_languages" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

RecyclerView in fragment:

```
private fun setAllLanguagesRecyclerView() {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        languagesList = viewModel.getAllLanguagesName().toMutableList()
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        val position = viewModel.getAllSelectedPosition()

        val adapter = AllLanguagesAdapter { allLangModel ->
            viewModel.insertRecentLanguages(allLangModel)
            sendBackValueToPreviousBackStack(allLangModel.langCode)
        }

        binding.allLangsRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter.submitList(languagesList)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            binding.allLangsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            setBackgroundToLanguagesRecyclerViewItem(
                recyclerView = binding.allLangsRecyclerView,
                position = position
            )
            setAdiveryNativeAd(adapter)
            setSearch(adapter)
        }
    }
}
```

AllLanguagesAdapter

```
class AllLanguagesAdapter constructor(private val langOnClick: (AllLangModel) -> Unit) :
ListAdapter<AllLangModel, AllLanguagesAdapter.ViewHolder>(AllLanguagesDiffCallBack) {


class ViewHolder constructor(
    private val binding: TranslateFromLanguageItemBinding,
    private val langOnClick: (AllLangModel) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    private var currentLangModel: AllLangModel? = null
    val innerBinding: TranslateFromLanguageItemBinding = binding


    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            currentLangModel?.let { allLangModel ->
                langOnClick(allLangModel)
            }
        }
    }


    fun bind(langModel: AllLangModel) {
        if (langModel.langCode.equals("en", true)){
            langModel.downStatus = true
        }
        this.currentLangModel = langModel
        binding.langModel = langModel
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): ViewHolder {
    val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: TranslateFromLanguageItemBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflate, R.layout.translate_from_language_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding, langOnClick)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val langModel: AllLangModel = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(langModel = langModel)
}
}

object AllLanguagesDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<AllLangModel>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: AllLangModel, newItem: AllLangModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

override fun areContentsTheSame(
    oldItem: AllLangModel,
    newItem: AllLangModel
): Boolean {
    return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recycler view inside NestedScrollView and add this property to the recylerview.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

this will manage the rest of the things

Comment: Did Not work budy!

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` is displaying all its contents because you've set its height to `wrap_content`. You need to constrain its height to get scrolling behaviour when the contents are larger than that height. (And specifically, the scrolling system is where you get the benefits of a `RecyclerView`, since it swaps a pool of views around to display the visible section of the list, rather than creating views for every item.)

So you should probably set a height for the `RecyclerView`, or its parent `ConstraintLayout` while allowing the `RecyclerView` to fill the available space. But why do you want to put a `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView` in the first place? They're both `ScrollingView`s, and a `RecyclerView` is already handling its specific use case - you don't need to wrap it in another scroller.

If it's because you want that `TextView` to scroll out of view, like when you scroll to the top of the list it appears, you'll honestly probably have an easier time just displaying it inside the `RecyclerView` itself, as the first item. Maybe with its own `ViewHolder` type, or possibly using a `ConcatAdapter` to have an Adapter that displays that text, and then the "real" adapter, so you can keep using the latter as-is without adding logic to account for the extra dummy item.

Comment: yes i do want that `TextView` to be scrolled out of view but i also have another `recyclerview` above the first `recyclerview` and the same `textview` that i want them all to be scrolled out the view. So i think I do need put recyclerviews inside `nestedScrollView`. If there is other way plz let me know.

Comment: @StackOverflower in that case you'll need to give them a defined height. Your `NestedScrollView` is like a window of a certain size, that allows you to see part of a larger layout (its contents) by scrolling that layout up and down. Your `RecyclerView`s are also like windows, that display larger contents by scrolling them. So you need to decide how big those windows should be. `wrap_content` just makes them as big as their contents, so they don't scroll at all